# $.widget is not a function jquery error in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, jquery, widget

I know this question has been around a lot with solution but none worked in my case.

I have installed Sm Revo theme with Magento v 2.1.0 and I'm getting this error.

[image]

So far I have tried following things

> /app/design/frontend/Sm/revo/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

In this file I have following content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <!-- ADD JQUERY -->
        <meta name="x_ua_compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
        <script src="jquery.js" />
        <script src="js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js" data-requiremodule="jquery"/>
        <script src="js/owl.carousel.js" data-requiremodule="jquery"/>
        <script src="js/lightslider.js" data-requiremodule="jquery"/>
        <script src="js/jquery.elevatezoom.js" data-requiremodule="jquery"/>
        <script src="js/jquery.cookie.min.js" data-requiremodule="jquery"/>
        <script src="js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js" data-requiremodule="jquery"/>
        <script src="js/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js" data-requiremodule="jquery"/>
        <script src="js/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js" data-requiremodule="jquery"/>
        <script src="js/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js" data-requiremodule="jquery"/>
        <script src="js/easyResponsiveTabs.js" data-requiremodule="jquery"/>
        <script src="js/yttheme.js" data-requiremodule="jquery"/>

        <!-- ADD CSS  -->
        <css src="css/styles-m.css" />
        <css src="css/styles-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"/>
        <css src="css/print.css" media="print" />       
        <css src="css/css-fix.css" />
        <css src="css/ytextend.css" />
        <css src="css/yttheme.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

I have tried replacing `<script src="jquery.js" />` with `<remove src="jquery.js" />`
 as mentioned somewhere as a fix but it worked on my local but didn't work on test server hosted on google.
Also tried with different magento version but same error occurred.

Answer (score -1):

Store > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > JavaScript Settings
Set Merge JavaScript files to Yes.
That solved the issue for me (+ lowering considerably the number of requests).